# position payload in attribute for action?

Tags: vuex

Where I must type 'payload' in attributes for action?
In {} brackets or outside?
1 option:

```
    async loadData( {state, payload, dispatch}) {
      try {
...omitted
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },
```

2 option:

```
async loadData( {state,dispatch}, payload) {
  try {
    ...omitted
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument can be destructured to access a lot of useful things to access some state, run a quick mutation etc...more details here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions

The second argument is the actual payload that you are passing if you want to update something with some data.

Not to confuse with a `dispatch` where you pass the `name` + `payload` directly.

So, option 2.